# How can I prevent an Axis or Plot in MATLAB GUIDE from overtaking the entire GUI?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, plot, axis

I am currently developing a GUI in MATLAB R2013a and am trying to use the preset zoom and rotate functions in the toolbar. I have encountered a large problem a few days ago and have tried many things to fix it but with no luck. Essentially, when using the MATLAB preset zoom functions, zooming into a 3D plot causes the axis to overtake the entire GUI. For simplicity, I attach a photo of a very simple GUI where this error occurs:

[image]

One attempt at solving the problem has been to create the axis as a child of a panel:

```
function uipanel1_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to uipanel1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    empty - handles not created until after all CreateFcns   called
handles.axes1 = axes('parent',hObject);
guidata(hObject,handles);
```

But the issue still occurs. I have also tried making small panels around the axis that are stacked on top of the UI but no luck. I have read many discussion threads and have not found a fix to a problem like this.

Does anyone have an idea of what can be done to resolve this issue? Any help would be great appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what is the panel used for. Is it linked somehow to the axes or are they both totally separate uicontrols?

Comment: I did not need the panel but my idea was to create a panel then have an axis as its child. I was hoping that this would prevent the axis from exceeding the boundary of the panel during a zoom, but this did not work. Basically, I want to restrict the axis to a certain size to implement the same zoom behaviour as in a 2D plot.

Comment: That's weird, I tried the example with zoom/rotate buttons in the toolbar and it works fine. How did you implement the callbacks?

Comment: I just use the built-in functions, no change to the callbacks. What version of MATLAB are you running?

Answer (score 0):

The unpleasant effect seems not related to the way the GUI has been implemented. The same occurs when zooming a 3D graph in a simple Figure.
The reason, unfortunately, is in the different behaviour of the "zoom" tool on 2D and 3D graphs:

On 2D graphs it changes the `limits of the axis`.

On 3D graphs it changes the "`view`" (`CameraViewAngle`)

More details are provided in the MatLab help.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I had actually found the same documentation about the 3D graphs. I was hoping that there would be a way to draw the axis inside of a panel in my UI and have this restrict the "view" but it does not seem to be working. Do you know if there are any workarounds from this zoom property? Sure I am not the only one that wants to use 3D graphs in their UI...

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone runs into this issue, I did not find a solution. Instead, I ended up making my GUI smaller and creating a separate figure where axes are created and the object is plotted.